# Getting some values from another website

Tags: c#

I am creating a website for getting live rate from gold to euro. This is the website that I am going to use: http://www.24hgold.com/english/gold_silver_prices_charts.aspx?money=Euro

At the moment, I plan to do is to view the source of the site and search for this portion: `<span id="lbGoldGramEurValue" class="number" style="font-weight:bold;">` then I can get the rate of gold in gram for euro. What is this technique called? then I can find other samples in .NET.

Is that the only way to do or any other advance and simpler way to do so?

Comment: I think you should be looking out for web services which give you these values, parsing values is not a good idea (what if they update the site, change the ids .....)

Comment: the technique is called [Screen Scraping](http://www.dotnetperls.com/scraping-html). But, Seriously, consider [Free webservices](http://softwaretopic.informer.com/free-web-services-for-gold-rates/) as this is a much better option

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the source of some website from asp.net code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386189/get-the-source-of-some-website-from-asp-net-code)

Comment: take a look a this site.. http://dgcsc.org/goldprices.xml. There are all the gold quotation in various currency and in XML format...

Comment: @2GDev, that is the site I am looking for. Thanks a lot. do you know the same xml site with providing silver exchange as well? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry but i can't find the silver quotation... i've googled few words but nothing about silver....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "web scraping" and is generally a bad idea. The main reason I say this is that your app is fragile to changes in the markup of a 3rd-party website. All they need to do is one of a) change the `id`, b) change the `class` or c) change the `style` of that element and your app goes kaput.

A far better approach (although perhaps not free) is to search for a public webservice which provides the information you need. A quick search came up with:

- http://www.xignite.com/xMetals.asmx
- http://www.webservicex.net/WS/WSDetails.aspx?WSID=10 (Currency converter, allows from XAU to EUR)

I should also note that web scraping another site may well infringe their copyright.

Answer (score 1):

you will have to parse the HTML that you grab from that URL so you can get to the element.

the technique is called HTML parsing. but your solution could have problems, as you'll have to update your code, everytime the HTML structure for that site changes.

can't you find an API that could provide you with those figures?

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/386189/get-the-source-of-some-website-from-asp-net-code they have some good examples on the answers